# how to calculate summary using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var data = [
    {
        _id:            '6d2847090a6a1b',
        user_id:        '580da5653bd3cc5802f6c37c',
        name:           'aaaa',
        sum: 250
        
    },
    
    {
        _id:            '75f36d2847090a6a36580871',
        user_id:        '3bd3cc5802f6c37c580da565',
        name:           'bbbb',
       sum :30
    },
    {
        _id:            '6a3087184367090a6a3e58fd284',
        user_id:        '2f63bc580c37c580da565d3c',
        name:           'ccc',
        sum :100
    }
];


var giftedObject = [];
data.forEach(function(userSummary){
    userSummary.numberOfGifted = Math.floor(userSummary.sum / 100);
    for(var i = 0; i < userSummary.numberOfGifted; i++){
        giftedObject.push({
            user_id: userSummary.user_id,
            name: userSummary.name,
            gifted_point: 1,
            active: true
        });
    }
    
});
var result = {giftedObject: giftedObject};
console.log(result);
```

Above is my code .here when ever user reached 100 points giftedObjectobject will create.

if user reached 100 point that time one object will create

if user reached 200 point that time two object will create

after creating object we need to reduce the gifted values from data

expected result :

gifted object result:

```
{
        active:true
        user_id:        '580da5653bd3cc5802f6c37c',
        gifted_point: 1
        name:           'aaaa',


    },

    {
         active:true
        user_id:        '580da5653bd3cc5802f6c37c',
        gifted_point: 1
        name:           'aaaa',
    },
    {

         active:true
        user_id:        '2f63bc580c37c580da565d3c',
        gifted_point: 1
        name: 'ccc',
    }
```

final data result

```
 {
            _id:            '6d2847090a6a1b',
            user_id:        '580da5653bd3cc5802f6c37c',
            name:           'aaaa',
            sum: 248

        },

        {
            _id:            '75f36d2847090a6a36580871',
            user_id:        '3bd3cc5802f6c37c580da565',
            name:           'bbbb',
           sum :30
        },
        {
            _id:            '6a3087184367090a6a3e58fd284',
            user_id:        '2f63bc580c37c580da565d3c',
            name:           'ccc',
            sum :99
        }
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're trying to do. `everything working fine but after creating object we need to reduce (minus) in sum value`

Comment: Along the lines of @Jamiec, you want to create a new list of objects, while modifying the original list of objects in place to reduce the sum of each entry by the number of objects created for the new list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subtract `gifted_points` from the sum.

```js
var data = [{ _id: '6d2847090a6a1b', user_id: '580da5653bd3cc5802f6c37c', name: 'aaaa', sum: 250 }, { _id: '75f36d2847090a6a36580871', user_id: '3bd3cc5802f6c37c580da565', name: 'bbbb', sum: 30 }, { _id: '6a3087184367090a6a3e58fd284', user_id: '2f63bc580c37c580da565d3c', name: 'ccc', sum: 100 }],
    giftedObject = [];

data.forEach(function (userSummary) {
    var i,
        gifted_point = Math.floor(userSummary.sum / 100);

    userSummary.sum -= gifted_point;
    for (i = 0; i < gifted_point; i++) {
        giftedObject.push({
            user_id: userSummary.user_id,
            name: userSummary.name,
            gifted_point: 1,
            active: true
        });
    }
});

result = { giftedObject: giftedObject };
console.log(data);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i need to get two different objects one for final data and one for giftedObject

Answer (score 0):

How about decrementing the sum inside the for-loop?

```
for(var i = 0; i < userSummary.numberOfGifted; i++){
    giftedObject.push({
        user_id: userSummary.user_id,
        name: userSummary.name,
        gifted_point: 1,
        active: true
    });
    userSummary.sum -= 1; // <--- add this line
}
```